# Get the 'compatible' version of Oracle Database using JDBC APIs

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to know the '**compatible**' version of the Oracle Database via some JDBC APIs. Basically, I'm interested in the the value of an init parameter '**compatible**'.

For example, if I'm connecting to an Oracle Database 19c, then I want to know the compatibility setting the 19c Database supports. (Say) If it is compatible to handle Oracle 12.1.0.2 functionality, then I want to know that in my JDBC code via some readily available APIs, so that I can avoid querying views like v$parameter to get the value of '**compatible**' parameter.

I was expecting a class `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` to have such a facility. But I didn't find any relevant method defined under `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData`. The methods `getDatabaseMajorVersion` and `getDatabaseProductVersion` seem to return the software released version which I am not interested in. Appreciate if you know any API or technique to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is one because the meaning of parameters is highly dependent on particular database engines and would be extremely hard to abstract out.  If anything, I could imagine that Oracle's [oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/index.html?oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html) class implementing something to query initialization parameters via the [oracle.jdbc.AdditionalDatabaseMetaData interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/index.html?oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html) but that wasn't one of the extensions Oracle has chosen to build thus far.

In your example, a 19c database with `compatible` set to 12.1.0.2 would support 99% of the new 19c functionality.  The only things that wouldn't work would be anything that changed the format of the data files on disk.  There tend to be very few such features-- the vast majority of new functionality is implemented at a much higher level of the stack.  This is fundamentally different than, say, what the compatibility level setting on SQL Server means.  It certainly wouldn't make sense for `getDatabaseMajorVersion` and `getDatabaseProductVersion` to return information based on the setting of the `compatible` parameter because that would be misleading for the vast majority of version-specific issues.